# Java Swing Timer only fires once with JButton

Tags: java, swing, timer

I have a problem with the building of a simple Swing timer project. I am trying to build a count down timer. The only issue seems to be that I have to press the JButton everytime I want to decrement a second. I would like the Timer to start and KEEP running once I press the 'start' JButton. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
package package1;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;




public class MyTimerPanel extends JPanel {

    private Timer javaTimer1;
    private JButton start1;
    private JLabel label;   
    private JLabel timer1;
    private TimerListener listener;
    private  int count = 30;


    public MyTimerPanel() 
    {

        label = new JLabel("Timer");
        timer1 = new JLabel("timer1");
        javaTimer1 = new Timer(1000, listener);
        listener = new TimerListener();
        javaTimer1.addActionListener(listener);

        javaTimer1.start();
        javaTimer1.setRepeats(true);



        timer2 = new JLabel("timer2");
        timer3 = new JLabel("timer3");


        start1 = new JButton("Start Timer 1");
        start1.addActionListener(listener);



        //Add
        add(label);
        add(timer1);

        add(start1);

    }       


    public class TimerListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            if( e.getSource() == start1)
            {

                count--;
                timer1.setText("" + count);


            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What is `CountDownTimer`?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  An MCVE needs a `main(String[])` to put it on-screen, but check the document for further details.

Comment: CountDownTimer is an object that I have created. This will feed create a time like "00:01:25" and then I have a dec() method that removes a second. The problem is somewhere with the JButton and action event relationship I think.

Comment: The button is NOT the source of the ActionEvent. Add a System.out.println(...) statement to you code to see what the source is. Also display output from inside the if statement to see if you code is executing. These are basic problem solving techniques you should use BEFORE you post a question. `What is CountDownTimer?` you were asked that question in your last posting on this topic (http://stackoverflow.com/q/21199431/131872). Why do you keep posting code we can't compile?

Comment: The code inside the loop is executing. If I put a sysout statement it will print it once and then it will terminate. My timer starts at 00:00:15. When I hit the start1 button the label changes to 00:00:14, then when i click again to ...13, etc. The count down timer is working, except it needs me to hit the button everytime. I'm sorry I keep including countdowntimer, this is literally my second post. I will edit it to make it as simple as possible, and I really do not understand what you mean by it is not the source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "The only issue seems to be that I have to press the JButton everytime I want to decrement a second."

- Look at your `AtionListener`. All it does is check if the source is the buttom, so the source will never be the timer, meaning for all timer event that occur, nothing will happen. Just because you *call it* `TimerListener` doesn't make it an actual listener for the timer.
- Use a different listener for the button, where you use it to call start in the timer. and take out the source check in the `TimerListener`

Something like this. All I do is take out the button check in the `TimerListener`, and also give button its own liestener that starts the timer, and it works fine.

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class TestTimer extends JPanel {

    private JButton start1;
    private JLabel label;
    private JLabel timer1;
    private TimerListener listener;
    private int count = 30;
    private Timer javaTimer1 = new Timer(1000, null);

    public TestTimer() {

        label = new JLabel("Timer");
        timer1 = new JLabel("timer1");
        javaTimer1 = new Timer(1000, new TimerListener());
        javaTimer1.setRepeats(true);

        start1 = new JButton("Start Timer 1");

        add(label);
        add(timer1);
        add(start1);

        start1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                javaTimer1.start();
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestTimer());
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TimerListener implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (count == 0) {
                javaTimer1.stop();
            } else {
                count--;
                timer1.setText("" + count);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked very well. Thank you!. Would I have to do that to each button if I had 3 different timers with 3 different buttons?

Answer (score 0):

If dec() is your own method that removes a second it's perfectly normal that only one sec is removed when you hit the button. If you want to see the timer that goes down you should separate in two thread using swingworker. So in one thread you make the count down and after every second that you remove, make a publish to update the gui.

Comment: But If I remove the JButton out of the picture and just have the following then my timer1 label in the jframe updates and works perfectly. It counts down every second. `public class TimerListener implements ActionListener
 {  
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
  
   
   a.dec();
   timer1.setText(a.toString());
   
    
   
   
    
    
     
    
       
   
  
  }
  
 }`

Comment: But you have said that it needs you to hit in order to update, using swing worker you can hit the button one time and the label will change until the countdown reaches zero.

Comment: Ok I can try that. I'm not really sure as to how to update the GUI, do U have any links or suggestions where I can look this stuff up? Thanks

Comment: if you search on google you'll find a lot of article; basically you define a class that implement the swing worker overriding three principal method and in your action listener you create the swing worker and launch it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate ActionListeners.

1. You add an ActionListener to the button. This ActionListener simply starts the Timer.
2. You create the Timer with a second ActionListener. This ActionListener decrements the time.